# How can I add this module to my Android Studio project?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I've tried adding [this](https://github.com/antoniom/Millisecond-Chronometer) millisecond chronometer widget to my android studio project using multiple different guides but none of them seemed to work for this specific file. This is my first time trying to add a module to an Android Studio project and I wasn't sure what to do. Also, how can I use it after I add it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This project doesn't have any external dependencies, it doesn't use resources. The simplest way would be to just copy the `Chronometer.java` file to your project.

If you really would like to build it as a module (kinda overkill), the way would be to import it as a gradle module: `File -> New -> Import module`. Point to a directory, then name the module, let's say "chronometer". You would need to add the following line to your global `settings.gradle` file (studio probably does that automatically):

```
include ':app', ':chronometer'
```

And in `build.gradle` of a module, where you want to use that new module, put:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':chronometer')
}
```

And that would do, but as I say, it's reeeeally unnecessary.

Comment: Great! Thank you very much. But now how would I go about adding that to my xml? Sorry I know this is a stupid question, but I'm very new to android development.

Comment: Sure, check out [this file](https://github.com/antoniom/Millisecond-Chronometer/blob/master/res/layout/main.xml) from the project you've linked, the answer lies within. Also, if you feel I have answered your question, mark my answer as accepted.

Comment: Perfect! And sorry, I'm also new to using this site for help, I'll do that right away.